# Fluctuative current and voltage graph shown by LabQuest 2

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, potential, voltage, electronics

I was in physics class and was tasked to measure current and voltage of a circuit using [LabQuest 2](https://www.vernier.com/product/labquest-2/). The circuit was connected to a battery, which means it's a DC circuit. But when I use the LabQuest for measuring, it shows non constant graph of both voltage vs. time and current vs. time. The current seems constant most of the time but change a bit. But the voltage seems fluctuative, as in a sinusoidal function. How does this happen? I was also told to use the average value generated by the LabQuest as the written data, is it because the data is most represented by average value?

Comment: Are you getting random fluctuations or an **actual** "uniform" sinusoidal signal? If it's the latter, your source cannot possibly be DC.

Comment: I am no expert for said device. But the most likely explanation is that the device applies auto-scale to the signal. I.e. it magnifies the scaling of the voltage/current axis until it "finds" the tiniest fluctuations (which may be real or may be caused by the imperfection of the instrument itself). By choosing the average, you deliberately eliminate fluctuations, which is of course only appropriate if you are not interested in the fluctuations (e.g. because you know beforehand that it is a DC signal).

Comment: Note, that these kinds of questions should rather be asked on electrical engineering SE.

Comment: The fluctuation seems random though, not uniform. And sorry, I thought it may be asked in physics as it's about measurement.